# How to copy a worksheet from a workbook to new Workbook in Epplus?

Tags: c#-4.0, epplus-4

```
    try
    {

     FileInfo resultFile = new FileInfo(@"C:\\Users\\350154\\Desktop\\vb workouts\\testsample.xlsx");
     if (resultFile.Exists)
         {
            resultFile.Delete();
         }
ExcelPackage masterPackage = new ExcelPackage(new FileInfo(@"C:\\Users\\350154\\Desktop\\vb workouts\\testsample.xlsx"));

                ExcelPackage pckg = new ExcelPackage(new FileInfo(@"C:\\Users\\350154\\Desktop\\vb workouts\\y.xlsx"));

                string workSheetName = pckg.Workbook.Worksheets[1].Name;
               masterPackage.Workbook.Worksheets.Add(workSheetName, pckg.Workbook.Worksheets[1]);
              masterPackage.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("test");
              masterPackage.SaveAs(new FileInfo(@"C:\\Users\\350154\\Desktop\\vb workouts\\testsample.xlsx"));
}catch(excption e){
console.writeline();
}
```

Hi,Am using Epplus to copy a worksheet from a workbook to a new workbook and create as a ne worksheet.My code is above.I am using Epplus4.0 .But am not able to process my code.**Error is arising:Error Saving File**
please help me to solve my issue.